# Selenium on element click, ElementNotInteractableException

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click on element with href to delete pending posts in FB group, but selenium crashes after second `.click()`. Using the same loop, I can add posts to group without any problems; The "delete button" list is valid, because when I try  `System.out.println("Delete link: " + delete.get(i).getLocation());` I get real locations.

```
while (true){
      if (isloadComplete(driver) && driver.getTitle().contains("My Group")){
         List<WebElement> add = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@data-tooltip-content='approve']"));
         List<WebElement> delete = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[@data-tooltip-content='delete']"));
         List<WebElement> articles = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@role='article']"));

         System.out.println("Add links: " + add.size());
         System.out.println("Delete links: " + delete.size());
         System.out.println("Articles: " + articles.size());

         for(int i = 0; i< articles.size(); i++){
             System.out.println("Delete link: " + delete.get(i).getLocation());
             if (articles.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains(".com") | articles.get(i).getText().toLowerCase().contains("http")){

                 //System.out.println("Article: " + articles.get(i).getText());

                  delete.get(i).click();
                  WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[@data-testid='delete_post_confirm_button']")));
                       element.click();

                  }else{
                     add.get(i).click();
                  }

               }
               break;
           }
```

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
>   Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
>   System info: host: 'rostyslav-System-Product-Name', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.10.0-32-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{moz:profile=/tmp/rust_mozprofile.6twl2JYTeRMH, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=55.0.2, platformVersion=4.10.0-32-generic, moz:processID=26485.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=linux}]
>   Session ID: 562a62e4-3aaf-45e3-b7f2-46f741f798a3
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:272)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:82)
>       at Main$HelloRunnable.run(Main.java:67)
>       at Main.main(Main.java:36)

Comment: Which line in the above code causes this exception? `delete.get(i).click();`?

Comment: @SergeyKorol yes

Answer (score 0):

You should wait for `elementToBeClickable` before actual `click` call. Just tune the following line a bit, the same way you did after (via `WebDriverWait`):

```
delete.get(i).click();
```

Comment: This didn't help, I get timeout, in next WebDriverWait that is looking for "confirm" button, but there is no one, cuz .click() didnt work. I just skip it with try-catch and after, I delete all posts on page,  refresh page and undeletted posts get deleted... I used to set timeout to 30sec, still doesn't helps )

Comment: @LittleFox could you update your post with latest code and exact lines where are you getting error? Stacktrace would be also appreciated.